# Why does not entry point address start at 0x400000

Tags: linux, elf

On Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64

my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("helloworld\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Build**:
`gcc -o test test.c`

**Show entry point address**:

```
readelf -h ./test

ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1060
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          14824 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         13
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         31
  Section header string table index: 30
```

Why does entry point address start at 0x1060 ? not 0x40000 ?

Comment: Why should it be 0x40000?

Comment: Why not?  With ASLR it will be relocated to a random address anyway.

Comment: You might be thinking of non-position independent executables, where the binary is loaded around address `0x400000`.  Compile with `-no-pie` to get this.  This lets the 4MB big page at virtual address 0 stay unmapped, so that anything within 4MB of a null pointer will trap if dereferenced (e.g. `p->member` where `p` is null).  But with ASLR there will be nothing mapped anywhere near address 0 anyway, so this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary is relocatable, and the segments have been packed against each other. The `.text` segment starts at 0x1050 in the file, and the entry point is relative to its location in the file, not the location it will ultimately be loaded.

For a non-relocatable file try `readelf -h /usr/lib/klibc/bin/sh`. This file is simpler in a number of ways, including not using an interpreter but actually being loaded as-is by the kernel.

We're not in `x86` anymore. Relocatable binaries are the default for everything now, not just shared libraries. It's no longer a great pain to do relocatable stuff, and in a certain way it's cheaper than non-relocatable now because we have to emit the vector table anyway because the processor doesn't have 64 bit displacement.

As Nate Eldredge points out, compiling with `-no-pie` yields a non-relocatable binary, and I have verified the expected start address appears.

Comment: Thanks for Joshua and Nate Eldredge 
I read the text book but can't understand. I can get the expected start address now.